# Permission denied (publickey). when connecting to AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I can't ssh to my remote server even tho I already put there my public_key. Here is the log when I did a "ssh -v ubuntu@website.com":

```
ssh -v ubuntu@plumbersserver.net  
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to plumbersserver.net [::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to plumbersserver.net [54.206.17.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA cf:a8:01:57:1f:f6:3f:9e:6a:2a:8f:e4:0c:ce:8d:a3
debug1: Host 'plumbersserver.net' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kevinyee/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please help. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where did you put your public key?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are logging in as 'ubuntu' user, in the ec2 instance, your public key should be appended to the file: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys. If the file does not exist, create the file with your public key contents and ensure that the file permissions is set to 600.

Answer (score 0):

Try these troubleshooting steps:

1. Ensure that your public key has been saved in the correct directory: 
   `/home/ec2-user/.ssh`
2. Ensure your public key has the correct permissions assigned to it: **0600** 
   `chmod 0600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/your_public_key`
3. Ensure that you are using the correct private key when connecting by using the `-i` flag for ssh. `ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key.pem ec2-user@website.com` 
   Make sure your private key also has the correct permissions of **0600**

If you are unable to connect to the instance at all in order to verify steps 1 & 2 above, then stop the instance, detach the root volume, and attach and mount it to an available instance.